# Calculating average NDVI pixel-by-pixel

Tags: ndvi, vegetation-index

Ok, I have loaded a .tif file using python3. I calculated the NDVI by making calculations to the different channels of the .tif. I marked an area where I want to calculate the average NDVI. The problem is that some pixels inside the marked area have negative values. So, the rationale is to add all the NDVI pixel values inside the marked area, sum them and divide them with their population in order to get the average value of NDVI inside the area. My question is what do I do with the negative values? Do I add both positive and negative values in order to calculate the summation?

Comment: Have you looked at those negative pixels to try and determine *why* they went negative?  For example, man-made objects can generate a negative NDVI. If that were the case, you might want to reclass the negative pixels to NULL so that they are excluded from any subsequent calculations.

Comment: Yes, you should calculate the average of all positive and negative values. The range of NDVI is -1 to 1, and negative values can occur when there is little to no vegetation. If you were to exclude or change the negative values in some ways your final NDVI within the marked area would be artificially inflated and would not represent the true average.